# Is there anyway to pass a WPF Control through an XAML event listener to be used in the code behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, xaml, wpf-controls

Let's say I have two simple WPF controls:

```
<Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Test"  Click="btnOne_Click" />
<Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="TestTwo" />
```

Is there anyway I can pass the `btnTwo` control to the `Click` event in `btnOne` in WPF so that I can use it the `btnOne_Click` function?

I know I can obviously reference the button directly in the code, but I would like to pass it through to minimize my functions instead of having 4 different functions that do the same thing.

Comment: In the code behind of this control you already have access to both buttons. In btnOne's event handler just put in  something like   var text = btnTwo.Context.ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is already done on the framework per se.

Look at the definition of the handler for click:

```
Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);
```

As you can see you have a sender parameter, that's the object which fired the event.

So, if you set:

```
<Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Test"  Click="btn_Click" />
<Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="TestTwo"  Click="btn_Click" />
```

then you can use the sender paramter to check which button has been clicked:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn == null)
        return;

   switch(btn.Name)
   {
       case "btnOne":
          //...
          break;
       case "btnTwo":
          //...
          break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thanks! I'm still very new to WPF, but this makes total sense. And in your switch, I made the cases = to btnOne.Name just in case I messed up typing it out :). Will mark as answer when I'm able to

Answer (score 1):

I would have two different `Button` click handlers, that both references the same method. This will allow you to have two different handlers if you need different business logic for each one, but still share the same core-code.

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Test"  Click="Button1_Click" />
<Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="TestTwo" Click="Button2_Click"/>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HandleButtonClick();
}

public void Button2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    HandleButtonClick();
}

private void HandleButtonClick()
{
    ....
}
```

If you do it this way, you don't have to handle which `Button` the click came from, which makes your code a lot cleaner and improves readability.

Comment: Awesome idea thank you. I just implemented it and I agree it is much more clean and way easier to manage. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button x:Name="btnOne" Content="Test"  Click="btnOne_Click" />
<Button x:Name="btnTwo" Content="TestTwo" />


public void btnOne_Click(object sender, RoutedEvents e){

     btnTwo.Background = Brushes.LightBlue;
     btnOne.BackGround = Brushes.Red;
}
```

You already have that ability.